# Can I use a Google Form to check the status of a student's paperwork that is recorded in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheets filled in with student names and the status of a paper form.  I need to email parents to have them complete the paper form if it is missing.  But every time I send this email the first question I get is Doesn't my kid already have this form completed and on file?

So I would like to create a Google form where parents can enter the name of their student and it will show whether or not there is completed paperwork.

I can find how to pre-populate forms but that's not what I want.  I need it to show a response based on the information a parent enters.

Answer (score 0):

that's not really how Google Form was intended to be used. (eg. it's unfortunately not possible). you will need to redo your approach... you could create a new spreadsheet in which you would use `IMPORTRANGE` formula and import column of names only and send this new spreadsheet to the parents. this way when they press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find their kiddo a cell gets highlighted or just not found.